# Apply script on destination page when i click on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code, two HTML files, one JS and one CSS. What I want is when I click on the anchor tag in page1.html, then remove div `.orange` from the destination page slider.html.

page1.html

```
<body>    
    <a  class="slider" href="slider.html"> goto slider </a>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
</body>
```

slider.html

```
<body>
    <a class="page1" href="page1.html"> goto page1 </a>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
</body>
```

css

```
.red,.blue,.yellow,.green,.orange,.black {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
.orange{
    background: orange;
}
.black {
    background: black;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.slider',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        $('.orange').remove();
    });
});
```

give me some direction how can we communicate between two html files or how can we reload script after destination page loading is complete

i tried `window.onload` and `document.ready` but they are only works in current page not affecting in destination page,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless one page is within the iframe of another, or loaded in to another by AJAX, you cannot make pages communicate through JS like this. You would need to send some values through the querystring, or set a cookie or localStorage value in order to affect a page which is loaded at some point in the future.

Comment: Also, note that once the browser redirects the user to the next page, the script on the first page will stop running or even won't start running